# Unable to set the offset of a rotated box to an integer

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/0oyo7fcs/ - where I rotate a box. The box left offset starts at 150 and after rotating the box 15 degrees, it becomes 126.98826599121094. What's puzzling is that if I set the box left offset, after doing the rotate,  to be an an integer (fifth line from the bottom) it still comes back (fourth line from the bottom) with 14 decimals. Why can't I set this to be an integer?

Thanks.

```
$(function(){   
   var r=0;
    $("#rotate").click(function() {
        r+=15;
        $('#box').css({'-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+r+'deg)',
                                   '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+r+'deg)',
                                   '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+r+'deg)',
                                   '-o-transform': 'rotate('+r+'deg)',
                                   'transform': 'rotate('+r+'deg)'
                      });
        var off = $("#box").offset();
        off.left = Math.round(off.left);
        $("#box").offset(off);
        off = $("#box").offset();
        $("#left").html("Left = " + off.left);
     });
});
```